# How to prepare arrays for insertion into Firebase database?

Tags: arrays, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have a question about adding arrays to Firebase using AngularFire. Let's start with a quick example. What I tend to do when my users on the front end create a list is something like this:

```
angular.module("app", ["firebase"])

  .controller("createListCtrl", function($scope, $firebaseArray) {
      console.log("controller loaded");
      $scope.newList = [];
      $scope.addItemToList = function(itemlist) {
        console.log(itemlist);
        $scope.newList.push({
          "item": itemlist,
          "done": false
        });
      }

      $scope.sendToDb = function() {
        var ref = new Firebase("https://xxxxxx.firebaseio.com");
        var list = $firebaseArray(ref);
        list.$add({
          "list": $scope.newList
        }).then(function(ref) {
          var id = ref.key();
          console.log("added record with id " + id);
          console.log(list.$indexFor(id)); // returns location in the array
        })
      }
```

Ok all nice and dandy and it all works great but I then I read this article: 
https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-04-28-best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html

And I heard more people say to avoid arrays and I see the problem with array in Firebase, but what is the alternative, the article says this structure: 
`{foo: {counter: 1}, bar: {counter: 1}, baz: {counter: 1}};`

Is that really a better structure? I think it gets messy and I don't even know how I would achieve this structure starting with something like this:`$scope.newList = {};`. Is it really a problem doing it with an array. Are arrays really evil in Firebase? Thanks in advance for an explanation or a better alternative.

**edit**

This is how the list is stored in Firebase, which does not seem very good:

```
---uniqueID
     ---list
        ---0
            ---done:false
            ---item:"item1"
        ---1
            ---done:false
            ---item:"item2"
        ---2
            ---done:false
            ---item:"item3"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$firebaseArray` class, which you're already using, provides a mapping between Firebase's ordered collections (which use push ids for their keys) and AngularJS's array (which use regular arrays).

So in your controller's constructor instead of creating a local array for `itemList`, create a two-way synchronized `$firebaseArray`:

```
$scope.newList = $firebaseArray(new Firebase("https://xxxxxx.firebaseio.com"));
```

The blog post you're referring to served as the basis for quite a few changes to AngularFire since then. I highly recommend that you work through the [AngularFire development guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/). It will take at most a few hours and will answer many more questions than just this one (which is covered in the [section on synchronized arrays](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/synchronized-arrays.html)).

### Update

Thanks for the update. I now get what you're trying to do. So you initially want to keep the list of items client-side only, and then all at once save it to Firebase.

In that case, I'd write `sendToDb` like this:

```
$scope.sendToDb = function () {
  var ref = new Firebase("https://xxxxxx.firebaseio.com");
  var listRef = ref.push();
  $scope.newList.forEach(function(item) {
    var itemRef = listRef.push({ item: item.item, done: item.done });
    console.log('Added item with key: '+itemRef.key());
  });
}
```

*This uses the regular Firebase JavaScript SDK. But since AngularFire is built on top of that, they will co-exist without problems.*

So instead of pushing the array in one go, I simply loop over the items in it and push each of them.

Working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/frankvanpuffelen/vnh5dbwq/11/

Comment: Hi Frank. Thanks for your answer! So going for two-way binding is the answer here. I have been confused a lot by this, I will definetly take a look at the development guide. I already did a part of it, but I was really in the dark here. This will create directly an entry in Firebase when using the add method right? I used the local array method because I don't want to create directly a new entry in Firebase, but only when the user clicks a save button or something. You see where I am going?

Comment: The item is pushed to Firebase when you call `$add`, so that still happens under your control.

Comment: Thanks Frank. You're awesome. Second time you helped me out :)...AngularFire is changing so fast. In January I asked you also a question and it was in version 0.8 or something...

Comment: Hmm, although this is the right way to do it. It does not achieve exactly what I want.

Comment: OK. Just edit your question with the minimum code to run, the JSON that gets stored and the JSON you're looking to get.

Comment: Hi Frank, since I am just fiddling around I don't mind showing you my code in a fiddle->[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vnh5dbwq/10/) so it becomes a lot clearer what I am doing and what I want to achieve.

Comment: Ok, seems like this does not work: console says `error: Firebase.push failed: first argument  contains an invalid key ($$hashKey) in property '-JpnGeVeYwXZCQX6SJsJ'.  Keys must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", or "]"` or maybe I am just not getting it, but thanks anyway will see if I can figure it out.

Comment: Got it. AngularJS was adding some extra properties onto the item. I updated the code snippet and linked to a working fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for your time and patience Frank. I haven't come across any example of this problem on SO.